# Why my gameObjects are not dragged and snap?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a simple puzzle game in Unity. I have two objects and two targets.- I wrote script to drag my objects to their target location. I want my objects to snap at a different locations. My code is not letting me drag the game object as I wanted. I can only move one of the objects even if I move it. I can't drag it. It just appears at target position after a second it jumps to other object's target location.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class moveObject : MonoBehaviour
{    
    [SerializeField] private Transform objectPosition;/// target position

    private Vector3 initialPosition; ///objects return position if placed wrong

    private float deltaX, deltaY; 

    public static bool correctPosition; /// lock item if it is snapped to true location

    public float snapdifficulty; /// snapping range  

    void Start()
    {
        initialPosition = transform.position;        
    }

    void Update()
    { 
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && !correctPosition)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Vector2 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            Ray raycast = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            RaycastHit raycastHit;

            switch (touch.phase)
            {
                case TouchPhase.Began:   
                    if (Physics.Raycast(raycast, out raycastHit))
                    {
                        if (raycastHit.collider.name == this.name)

                        {
                            deltaX = touchPos.x;
                            deltaY = touchPos.y;

                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    if (Physics.Raycast(raycast, out raycastHit))
                    {
                        if (raycastHit.collider.name == this.name)
                        {
                            Debug.Log("move " + " " + this.name);
                            transform.position = new Vector3(touchPos.x = deltaX, touchPos.y = deltaY, initialPosition.z);
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case TouchPhase.Ended:      
                    if (Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x - objectPosition.position.x) <= snapdifficulty
                        && Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y - objectPosition.position.y) <= snapdifficulty)
                    {
                        transform.position = new Vector3(objectPosition.position.x, objectPosition.position.y, initialPosition.z);
                        correctPosition = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        transform.position = new Vector3(initialPosition.x, initialPosition.y, initialPosition.z);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing

```
transform.position = new Vector3(touchPos.x = deltaX, touchPos.y = deltaY, initialPosition.z);
```

in

```
case TouchPhase.Moved:
    if (Physics.Raycast(raycast, out raycastHit))
    {
        if (raycastHit.collider.name == this.name)
        {
            Debug.Log("move " + " " + this.name);
            transform.position = new Vector3(touchPos.x = deltaX, touchPos.y = deltaY, initialPosition.z);
        }
    }
    break;
```

which makes your object stick to the initial position where the touch started until you reach the `TouchPhase.Ended` case.

I guess what you rather would want is store the initial Delta:

```
private Vector2 initialDelta;
```

and set it in

```
case TouchPhase.Began:   
    if (Physics.Raycast(raycast, out raycastHit))
    {
        if (raycastHit.collider.name == this.name)
        {
            initialDelta = transform.position - touchPos;
        }
    }
    break;
```

And then later use this Delta to position the object

```
case TouchPhase.Moved:
    if (Physics.Raycast(raycast, out raycastHit))
    {
        if (raycastHit.collider.name == this.name)
        {
            Debug.Log("move " + " " + this.name);
            transform.position = touchPos + initialDelta + Vector3.forward * initialPosition.z;
        }
    }
    break;
```

---

#### In general

I would not let every object handle the raycast! This is pretty expensive.

Rather put your script on **one single controller** object in the scene and additionally store which object you hit.

You can then put all your moveable objects into a special [Layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) and filter your Raycast to only hit this specific layer.

Something like e.g.

```
// Set via the Inspector
public LayerMask raycastLayers;

private Transform currentlyDraggedObject;
```

and then get it in

```
case TouchPhase.Began:   
    if (Physics.Raycast(raycast, out raycastHit, layermask = (int)raycastLayers))
    {
        currentlyDraggedObject = raycastHit.transform;
        initialDelta = currentlyDraggedObject.position - touchPos;

        // Your component would now only store and provide public the target position
        objectPosition = currentlyDraggedObject.GetComponent<Moveable>().objectPosition;   
    }
    break;
```

and then later do the manipulation on the dragged object

```
case TouchPhase.Moved:
    if (currentlyDraggedObject)
    {
        Debug.Log("move " + " " + currentlyDraggedObject.name);
        currentlyDraggedObject.position = touchPos + initialDelta + Vector3.forward * initialPosition.z;
    }
    break;

case TouchPhase.Ended:   
    if(currentlyDraggedObject)
    {   
        if (Mathf.Abs(currentlyDraggedObject.position.x - objectPosition.position.x) <= snapdifficulty
            && Mathf.Abs(currentlyDraggedObject.position.y - objectPosition.position.y) <= snapdifficulty)
        {
             currentlyDraggedObject.position = new Vector3(objectPosition.position.x, objectPosition.position.y, initialPosition.z);
            correctPosition = true;
        }
        else
        {
            currentlyDraggedObject.position = new Vector3(initialPosition.x, initialPosition.y, initialPosition.z);
        }
    currentlyDraggedObject = null;
    }
    break;
```

---

*Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: I had no idea about I should layer them thanks ! that being said. When i touch on my object and move; objects location is updated only once and moving it according to delta seems like sending it to a bit irrelevant location right now